# Get PrincipalId when deploying ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is it possible to retrieve the ID of the user that is deploying the ARM template?

There is the [`subscription()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#subscription) that retrieves information about the subscription the template is being deployed to, including the subscription ID, I'm hoping there is something similar for the principal.

Comment: Interested in your scenario for it though...

Comment: In my ARM template I am provisioning Key Vault and I need the user that is deploying the ARM template to be added as a Principal. We currently do this manually, after the deployment is done, but I would rather automate this step.

Comment: Makes sense - please do open a feedback request on it from the link below.

Comment: @CloudSME Did you ever find a way to automate this?

Comment: This is unfortunately **still not possible 6 years later**. Here is a link to the feedback item created for this specific functionality [https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/76222226-0125-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/76222226-0125-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible using reference().

```
"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('appService')), '2016-08-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]"
```

Note the use of 'full' parameter in the reference() function.

Relevant docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource?tabs=json#reference

Comment: How do you use that in Bicep?

Comment: @AlexanderSkwar I have never used Bicep before but I found documentation for the same functions I'm using above:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-resource#reference

Comment: Wouldn't this just give you the identity of the web app? If that web app is using managed identity, that would not be the desired value.

Comment: @DanFriedman : Try this for managed identity : reference(managedIdentityResourceId, '2018-11-30', 'Full').properties.principalId

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible as of today (26.06.2017). This might change in the future. You can always create feedback item for that and track it.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

Function reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-deployment